# How to use regex as delimiter function while reading a file into numpy array or similar

Tags: python, regex, numpy, parsing

Well I have this txt file:

```
.xsh 1:
..sxi
..kuxz
...iucdb
...khjub
..kjb
.hjub 2:
..ind
..ljnasdc
...kicd
...lijnbcd
.split 3:
..asd
```

I want to load this file into a numpy array (because numpy is fast to work with) to make it faster I want to begin parsing while loading. So to say I want it to split the file on every delimiter

```
delim = '(^\.\w+\s\d+\:)'
```

Now I have tried to do it like this:

```
import numpy as np
import os,re
path = 'C:\\temp'
filename = 'file.txt'
delim = '(^\.\w+\s\d+\:)'
delimFunc = (lambda s: re.split(delim,s))
fname = os.path.join(path,filename)
ar=np.loadtxt(fname, dtype = str, delimiter = delimFunc)
print len(ar)
```

Here it does not split the way I want too, instead it splits on every newline. Is it possible to make numpy, pandas or any other fast library to behave the way I want to here?

i want the result:

```
[[.xsh 1:
..sxi
..kuxz
...iucdb
...khjub
..kjb]
[.hjub 2:
..ind
..ljnasdc
...kicd
...lijnbcd]
[.split 3:
..asd]]
```

Comment: how should it look after parsing? Can you post your desired data set?

Comment: `loadtxt` uses the simple string `split` method, not a `re` version.

Comment: Your second record begins with the parsed delimiter, and the same applies for the 3rd record.  `re.split` doesn't work like this...

Comment: Ooops, also the 1st record begins with the parsed delimiter — I had missed that.  `re.split` still doesn't work like this.

Answer (score 0):

I think `pandas` supports this out of the box, if that is an option for you.

have a look at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

the `sep` arg:

> sep : str, default ‘,’
>
> Delimiter to use. If sep is None, the C engine cannot automatically detect the separator, but the Python parsing engine can, meaning the latter will be used and automatically detect the separator by Python’s builtin sniffer tool, csv.Sniffer. In addition, separators longer than 1 character and different from '\s+' will be interpreted as regular expressions and will also force the use of the Python parsing engine. Note that regex delimiters are prone to ignoring quoted data. Regex example: '\r\t'

You can also turn pandas dataframes back into numpy arrays without too much trouble using the `.values` method iirc

(https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html)

Comment: I tried to change it to:
    ar=pandas.read_csv(fname, sep = '(\.\w+\s\d+\:)') no luck.

Comment: @PaalPedersen actually looking at your question again I'm not sure that this will be possible with any csv reader out of the box - your problem will be that all of them will split on new-line as that's pretty standard csv behaviour..
 If you pre-process the file you might want to replace newlines with some sort of custom delimiter (or just a comma if you're sure there are none in your data) - then you could reintroduce line breaks at the numbered records and then it would read like a csv fwiw.

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve it differently, but still faster than before:

```
import numpy as np
import os,re
import time
t1=time.time()
path = 'C:\\temp'
filename = 'file.txt'
delim = '(^\.\w+\s\d+\:)'
fname = os.path.join(path,filename)
ar=np.loadtxt(fname, dtype = str, delimiter = '\n')
x = np.array([],np.int32)
for (i,v) in enumerate(ar):
    if re.search(delim,v):
        x=np.append(x,i)

t2=time.time()
print np.split(ar,x)[1]
print 'Length of array:{0:d},took as long as {1:.2f} to complete'.format(len(x),(t2-t1))
```

Comment: This is equivalent to your solution: `d = re.compile(delim) ;  splitted = np.split(ar, np.nonzero([d.search(x) for x in ar])[0])` — however, both this and your solution introduce a zero length array before the 3 parts in which the original array is splitted — is this behaviour exactly what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I would go like this

```
...
d = re.compile(delim)
# np.nonzero in this case returns a 1-uple of arrays, we have to unwrap
ixs = np.nonzero([d.search(item) for item in ar])[0]
splitted = np.split(ar, ixs if ixs[0] else ixs[1:])
...
```

The `ixs if ixs[0] else ixs[1:]` expression takes care of the possibility of a valid "delimiter" in the first record, to achieve the type of result (i.e., no void record of records) that you have shown in the original question.

Comment: Both solutions does exactly what I need, but yours is much faster! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This anything like you're looking for?

```
s = """
.xsh 1: 
..sxi 
..kuxz 
...iucdb 
...khjub 
..kjb 
.hjub 2: 
..ind 
..ljnasdc 
...kicd 
...lijnbcd 
.split 3: 
..asd
"""
print(re.findall(r"(\.\w+ \d+:)\s*((?:.(?!\.\w+ \d+:))+)", s, re.M|re.DOTALL))
>>> [('.xsh 1:', '..sxi \n..kuxz \n...iucdb \n...khjub \n..kjb '), ('.hjub 2:', '..ind \n..ljnasdc \n...kicd \n...lijnbcd '), ('.split 3:', '..asd\n')]
```